# Setting end_date if a new identical row is inserted

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm having trouble with finding the most effective set of statements to handle historical data. Lets say i have two tables. a staging and a archive table. Everytime data is imported into the staging table i want to insert it into the archive table with following logic.

```
if circuitId = circuitId and checksum = checksum(*)
    then do nothing

if circuitId = circuiId and checksum <> checksum(*)
    then insert new row and set end_date of old row.

if rows exists in archive but not in staging
   then change delete_flag to 1
```

so far i've created below which handles the `delete_flag` and if `checksum = checksum(*)`, however i can't seem to figure out how to integrate if `checksum <> checksum(*)` and setting end_date on old row.

```
UPDATE ARCHIVE.F1_CIRCUITS n
        SET
            n.DELETE_FLAG = 1
        FROM
            ARCHIVE.F1_CIRCUITS n
                LEFT JOIN EXTRACT.F1_CIRCUITS o
                ON o."circuitId" = n.CIRCUITID
                WHERE o."circuitId" IS NULL;

INSERT INTO ARCHIVE.F1_CIRCUITS
            SELECT ("circuitId","circuitRef","name","location","country","lat","lng","alt","url", CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, NULL, HASH_MD5("circuitId","circuitRef","name","location","country","lat","lng","alt","url"), 'C', 0) FROM EXTRACT.F1_CIRCUITS o
            WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                              FROM ARCHIVE.F1_CIRCUITS n
                              WHERE o."circuitId" = n.CIRCUITID AND
                              HASH_MD5(o."circuitId",o."circuitRef",o."name",o."location",o."country",o."lat",o."lng",o."alt",o."url") = n.cheetax_checksum
                             );
```

**Staging Schema table**

```
CREATE TABLE EXTRACT.F1_CIRCUITS (
    "circuitId"  DECIMAL(11,0),
    "circuitRef" VARCHAR(255) UTF8,
    "name"       VARCHAR(255) UTF8,
    "location"   VARCHAR(255) UTF8,
    "country"    VARCHAR(255) UTF8,
    "lat"        DOUBLE PRECISION,
    "lng"        DOUBLE PRECISION,
    "alt"        DECIMAL(11,0),
    "url"        VARCHAR(255) UTF8
);
```

**Archive schema table**

```
CREATE TABLE F1_CIRCUITS (
    ID                      DECIMAL(18,0) IDENTITY,
    CIRCUITID               DECIMAL(11,0),
    CIRCUITREF              VARCHAR(255) UTF8,
    NAME                    VARCHAR(255) UTF8,
    LOCATION                VARCHAR(255) UTF8,
    COUNTRY                 VARCHAR(255) UTF8,
    LAT                     DOUBLE PRECISION,
    LNG                     DOUBLE PRECISION,
    ALT                     DECIMAL(11,0),
    URL                     VARCHAR(255) UTF8,
    START_TIMESTAMP TIMESTAMP,
    END_TIMESTAMP   TIMESTAMP,
    CHECKSUM        CHAR(32) UTF8,
    STATUS          CHAR(1) UTF8,
    DELETE_FLAG     DECIMAL(1,0)
);
```

Comment: What is the EXTRACT table?

Comment: woops Extract is the staging. changed everything to EXTRACT now instead of staging

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your scenario, I suggest to use Triggers and make auto the operations. 
The below Trigger will fire anytime you insert a new row into your EXTRACT table (conditions 1/2) or DELETE from there (condition 3), and will check for:

When INSERTING to the EXTRACT:

```
if circuitId = circuitId and checksum = checksum(*)
    then do nothing

if circuitId = circuiId and checksum <> checksum(*)
    then insert new row and set end_date of old row.
```

When DELETING from EXTRACT:

```
if rows exists in archive but not in staging
   then change delete_flag to 1
```

TRIGGER for your conditions:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER archiver
      AFTER INSERT OR DELETE
          ON EXTRACT.F1_Circuits
        REFERENCES OLD AS OLD NEW AS NEW
          FOR EACH ROW


    DECLARE

          v_extr_new_row VARCHAR2 (500); --- for storing new inserting row data
          v_extr_row_checksum RAW(500);  --- for storing new row as RAW
          v_encrypted_raw RAW(2048);     --- encrypted to md5 data
          v_arch_cir_id NUMBER (11) := 0;   --- circuitId from ARCHIVE table
          v_arch_checksum VARCHAR2 (32) := '0'; --- checksum from ARCHIVE table
          v_arch_last_chsum NUMBER (3);    --- for finding the latest data by checksum in ARCH table
          v_arch_start_date TIMESTAMP;   --- for finding the latest data by start_date in ARCH table

        BEGIN

         IF INSERTING THEN
              --- taking the inserting data into the variable for further converting to md5
              v_extr_new_row := :NEW."circuitId" || ',' || :NEW."circuitRef" || ',' ||  :NEW."name" || ',' ||
                                :NEW."location" || ',' ||  :NEW."country" || ',' ||  :NEW."lat" || ',' ||
                                :NEW."lng" || ',' ||  :NEW."alt" || ',' || :NEW."url";

              --- converting the inserting data to hash_md5, checksum
              v_extr_row_checksum := utl_raw.cast_to_raw(v_extr_new_row);
              v_encrypted_raw := dbms_crypto.hash(v_extr_row_checksum, 2);

                 --- taking the latest row from the ARCH table for changing the Updating the END_DATE;
                 SELECT START_TIMESTAMP, r_last_chsum, CHECKSUM, circuitId
                        INTO v_arch_start_date, v_arch_last_chsum, v_arch_checksum, v_arch_cir_id
                        FROM
                             (SELECT START_TIMESTAMP, ROW_NUMBER()
                                OVER (PARTITION BY arch_in.circuitId ORDER BY arch_in.START_TIMESTAMP DESC) r_last_chsum,
                                 CIRCUITID, CHECKSUM
                                 FROM ARCHIVE.F1_CIRCUITS arch_in
                                 WHERE arch_in.circuitId = :NEW."circuitId")
                           WHERE r_last_chsum = 1;


             ---- checking whether the data already exist in the ARCH table
             IF (v_arch_cir_id = :NEW."circuitId" AND v_arch_checksum <> v_encrypted_raw)
               THEN

                  ---- Update end_date for old row
                 UPDATE ARCHIVE.F1_CIRCUITS arch
                        SET arch.END_TIMESTAMP = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
                            WHERE arch.circuitId = :NEW."circuitId"
                                  AND arch.CHECKSUM = v_arch_checksum
                                  AND arch.START_TIMESTAMP = v_arch_start_date;

                 --- inserting the new data into ARCH table
                 INSERT INTO ARCHIVE.F1_CIRCUITS
                        (CIRCUITID, CIRCUITREF, NAME, LOCATION, COUNTRY, LAT, LNG, ALT, URL, START_TIMESTAMP, END_TIMESTAMP, CHECKSUM,
                             STATUS, DELETE_FLAG)
                        VALUES (:NEW."circuitId", :NEW."circuitRef", :NEW."name", :NEW."location", :NEW."country",
                                :NEW."lat", :NEW."lng", :NEW."alt", :NEW."url", CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, NULL, v_encrypted_raw, 'C', to_number (0));

                 ---- else if they are EQUAL then DO NOTHING, but if you need you can do;)
             ELSIF (v_arch_cir_id = :NEW."circuitId" AND v_arch_checksum = v_encrypted_raw)
                   THEN
                     dbms_output.put_line ('Do Nothing!');
    /*                 INSERT INTO ikrom.f1_circuits_arch   ---- ARCHIVE.F1_CIRCUITS
                        (CIRCUITID, CIRCUITREF, NAME, LOCATION, COUNTRY, LAT, LNG, ALT, URL, START_TIMESTAMP, END_TIMESTAMP, CHECKSUM,
                             STATUS, DELETE_FLAG)
                        VALUES (:NEW."circuitId", :NEW."circuitRef", :NEW."name", :NEW."location", :NEW."country",
                                :NEW."lat", :NEW."lng", :NEW."alt", :NEW."url", CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, NULL, v_encrypted_raw, 'C', to_number (0));*/
            END IF;

        END IF;

        IF DELETING THEN
                    --- taking the inserting data into the variable for further converting to md5
              v_extr_new_row := :OLD."circuitId" || ',' || :OLD."circuitRef" || ',' ||  :OLD."name" || ',' ||
                                :OLD."location" || ',' ||  :OLD."country" || ',' ||  :OLD."lat" || ',' ||
                                :OLD."lng" || ',' ||  :OLD."alt" || ',' || :OLD."url";

              --- converting the inserting data to hash_md5, checksum
              v_extr_row_checksum := utl_raw.cast_to_raw(v_extr_new_row);
              v_encrypted_raw := dbms_crypto.hash(v_extr_row_checksum, 2);

                 --- taking the latest row from the ARCH table for changing the Updating the END_DATE;
                 SELECT START_TIMESTAMP, r_last_chsum, CHECKSUM, circuitId
                        INTO v_arch_start_date, v_arch_last_chsum, v_arch_checksum, v_arch_cir_id
                        FROM
                             (SELECT START_TIMESTAMP, ROW_NUMBER()
                                OVER (PARTITION BY arch_in.circuitId ORDER BY arch_in.START_TIMESTAMP DESC) r_last_chsum,
                                 CIRCUITID, CHECKSUM
                                 FROM ARCHIVE.F1_CIRCUITS arch_in
                                 WHERE arch_in.circuitId = :OLD."circuitId")
                           WHERE r_last_chsum = 1;


             ---- checking whether the data already exist in the ARCH table
             IF (v_arch_cir_id = :OLD."circuitId")
               THEN

                  ---- Update end_date for old row
                 UPDATE ARCHIVE.F1_CIRCUITS arch
                        SET arch.DELETE_FLAG = 1
                            WHERE arch.circuitId = :OLD."circuitId"
                                  AND arch.DELETE_FLAG = 0;
              END IF;                   
           END IF;  

          EXCEPTION
             WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
               THEN
               ---- if no data found in ARCH table by SELECTING in INSERTING process then just INSERT the new row
                INSERT INTO ARCHIVE.F1_CIRCUITS
                            (CIRCUITID, CIRCUITREF, NAME, LOCATION, COUNTRY, LAT, LNG, ALT, URL, START_TIMESTAMP, END_TIMESTAMP, CHECKSUM,
                                 STATUS, DELETE_FLAG)
                            VALUES (:NEW."circuitId", :NEW."circuitRef", :NEW."name", :NEW."location", :NEW."country",
                                    :NEW."lat", :NEW."lng", :NEW."alt", :NEW."url", CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, NULL, v_encrypted_raw, 'C', to_number (0));

    END;
```

Important to say: when DELETING from Extract table than all rows with the same circuitId in ARCHIVE will be updated;
Also Grant execute on dbms_crypto for trigger running user;

Comment: @Peter Pik Please also Vote for the answer. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like for each **circuitid**, you want **end_date** / **end_timestamp** to always be null for the most recently inserted row. Why not just do that directly, and set the end timestamp for all rows which aren't the most recently inserted one?

```
update ARCHIVE.F1_CIRCUITS set end_timestamp = current_timestamp
  where end_timestamp is null
    and exists (select 1 from ARCHIVE.F1_CIRCUITS n
      where n.circuitid = f1_circuits.circuitid
        and n.start_timestamp > f1_circuits.start_timestamp);
```

On a different note, when I hear "every time something happens to this table, I want to do something to another table", my first thought is to use a trigger. If you do end up doing this in a trigger (or another PL/SQL block), this would also be easy if you assigned the checksum to a variable like **:new_checksum**; you could just do:

```
update ARCHIVE.F1_CIRCUITS set end_timestamp = current_timestamp
  where end_timestamp is null and circuitid = :new.circuitid and checksum <> :new_checksum;
```